# Hibernate nativeQuery with Sort order not working - Postgresql

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, spring-boot

I have a spring-boot app and talking to PostgreSQL using JPA. I have a custom query

```
SELECT * FROM public.user
INNER JOIN public.company
ON (public.user.company_id = public.company.id)
INNER JOIN public.truck
ON (public.user.id = public.truck.user_id)
INNER JOIN public.job
ON  (public.truck.id = public.job.truck_id)
WHERE public.company.id = 1
ORDER BY 1 USING < LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

When I run the above query in a SQL Editor like DBVisualizer or pgAdmin, I get the order and when I reverse it like

```
SELECT * FROM public.user
INNER JOIN public.company
ON (public.user.company_id = public.company.id)
INNER JOIN public.truck
ON (public.user.id = public.truck.user_id)
INNER JOIN public.job
ON  (public.truck.id = public.job.truck_id)
WHERE public.company.id = 1
ORDER BY 1 USING > LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

I still get the right result, but from my code, which is like

```
 @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * FROM public.user" +
        " INNER JOIN public.company" +
        " ON (public.user.company_id = public.company.id)" +
        " INNER JOIN public.truck" +
        " ON (public.user.id = public.truck.user_id)" +
        " INNER JOIN public.job" +
        " ON  (public.truck.id = public.job.truck_id)" +
        " WHERE public.company.id = :companyId" +
        " ORDER BY :columnNumber USING > LIMIT :pageSize OFFSET :offset")
List<Object[]> findJobsASC(@Param("companyId") Long companyId, @Param("pageSize") int pageSize, @Param("columnNumber") int columnNumber, @Param("offset") int offset);

 @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * FROM public.user" +
        " INNER JOIN public.company" +
        " ON (public.user.company_id = public.company.id)" +
        " INNER JOIN public.truck" +
        " ON (public.user.id = public.truck.user_id)" +
        " INNER JOIN public.job" +
        " ON  (public.truck.id = public.job.truck_id)" +
        " WHERE public.company.id = :companyId" +
        " ORDER BY :columnNumber USING < LIMIT :pageSize OFFSET :offset")
List<Object[]> findJobsDESC(@Param("companyId") Long companyId, @Param("pageSize") int pageSize, @Param("columnNumber") int columnNumber, @Param("offset") int offset);
```

Where `companyId = 1`, `pageSize = 10`, `columnNumber = 1` and `offset = 0`.

I get the same result when I run both the functions, its not ordered. I have tried using `ASC` and `DESC` without any success. I have also tried using the `columnName` instead of `columnNumber` and it still didn't make a difference.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you use standard SQL - `ORDER BY public.company.name ASC` instead of `ORDER BY 1 USING <`?

Comment: That is perfectly expressable using JPQL.

Comment: @manish, I have tried that without success through code.

Comment: @NeilStockton, you must remember I am using SpringBoot, so I am not configuring my entity manager and session, its handled by annotations and using JPQL would eventually give the same result as the query above, how different it is apart from the fact I have to overwrite my entity manager and session handlers.

Comment: You are using Spring and so behind the scenes it is using a JPA *native* query (rather than JPQL), so you lose datastore independence. Your loss.

Comment: @Neil is right, what you are trying to achieve is perfectly achievable through standard JPQL.  There is no need for Postgres-specific SQL.  Can you add some sample data for the tables, what you expect from the query and what you are actually seeing?

Comment: @NeilStockton, can you shed some more light on your statement with some example?

Comment: I've a better idea, why not just do a search for JPQL, and you'll find plenty of references on the web, maybe in the docs of your JPA implementation (Hibernate?) and they will explain to you what JPQL is, and how to write your query using it